# Test add-on by printing value in the browser console

Tags: testing, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, add-on, developer-tools

I am trying to test my add-on using the old way by choosing `Test as add-on...`.
Later on, I chose my Google Form and launch it to test the add-on. Prior to that, in the source code, I put console.logs to display the values. Can I print values using `console.log()` in the browser's console? How can I test and print values that are being store in my add-on?

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Did you you put the `console.log` statements on `.gs` or on `.html``  files? Does your add-on use the HTML Service? Does your project use the default or a standard Google Cloud Platform project?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` logs values to different locations depending on where it was called.

If `console.log` was called server-side (in the .gs), the logs are sent to Stackdriver Logging, which is visible in Google Cloud Platform or in `https://script.google.com/corp/home/executions`.

If `console.log` was called client-side (in the .html), the logs are sent to the browser console.

To view cloud logs, you can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_cloud_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console) using your standard GCP project ID.